# How To get seperate 3 string and remove '-'..?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String a="Apple-banana-pineapple";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(a,"-"); 

    String key = st.nextToken(); 
    String val = st.nextToken(); 
    System.out.println("key"+key);
    System.out.println("Values"+val);
}
```

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to StackOverflow. Request you to please explain your problem properly. Describe what issues are you facing. What output did you expect? and What output you got. And also, please add the question to the question body also. And if possible, please post a compilable code. Thanks :)

Comment: You just asked an answer ?? where is the question ?

Comment: did you try to split using split('-') and get the data in an array

Comment: i need o/p like this
1.apple
      2.banana
      3.pineapple

Comment: @kim.ramesh Please edit your question. There is an `edit` link below it. Click it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
   String a="Apple-banana-pineapple";
    String[] arr=a.split("-");
    for(String i:arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Out put:

```
   Apple
   banana
   pineapple
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split("-")` method of the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = a.split("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function.

```
String arr[]=a.split("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.split to accomplish what you want. Here is the api:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)